# XSLT 1.0 - change the order of lines

Tags: xslt, copy, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, apply-templates

I want to change the order of line cac:InvoiceLine depending on this node:

cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value

All InvoiceLines that have Item type=RC must be gruop at the end of lines, and all that have CU must be on the top.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of your input XML, and an example of what you want your result XML to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If the mentioned values are the only ones you are concerned about, then it seems like you could just sort alphabetically by that value; see [`xsl:sort`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#sorting). You could just put this inside the `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` where you process your invoice lines:

```
<xsl:sort select="cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value" />
```

On the other hand, if you only want to output only the line items with the mentioned values, you could select them separately. For example, assuming you have a template which matches your invoice lines, you'd first apply it to the 'CU' ones and then to the 'RC' ones:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="cac:InvoiceLine[cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value='CU']" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="cac:InvoiceLine[cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value='RC']" />
```